# Get checkboxes checked after data bound

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, telerik-grid

I have got Telerik MVC Grid bound with data with checkboxes. Now I need to get the checkboxes checked based on a condition. In the Grid I have a field "IsSelected" which is string. If the "IsSelected" is true only the checkboxes should get checked in the Grid. I need to perform this using jquery.

Comment: yes.....if true, the checkboxes should get checked in the Telerik Grid, using jquery

Comment: What do you mean by it's a field though.  Is it a column of data?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if IsSelected is an Attribute... JS variable... or Backend...

But the basic logic either way would be...

[**jsFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/6M3Lg/)

```
// obviously specify the checkboxes more than this
$('input:checkbox').each(function () {
    if ( $(this).attr('IsSelected') === 'true' ) {
        $(this).prop('checked', true);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if($('#IsSelected').val() == 'true'){
    $('#mygrid').find('input[type=checkbox]').attr('checked', true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
$('tbody > tr').each(function(){  // <-- loop through each row
    var $this = $(this);
    var $td = $this.children();
    if($td.eq(indexOfIsSelected).text() == 'true){  // <-- check the IsSelected column for text value
       $this.find('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked',true);  // <-- if true then check checkbox in that row
    }
});
```

Comment: hi...instead of 'tbody > tr', is it ok if I give the grid name ?

Comment: Yeah..  you just need to know how to get to the relevant items.  If you post some HTML markup it would have made it easier.  I was just giving a general answer

Comment: whether i m correct or not !!1 I have replaced $('tbody > tr').each(function() as $("#Rights").data('tGrid').each(function)()...Is it correct ?

Comment: is your table like this? http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/razor/grid/editingbatch?theme=black.. with the same `class="t-widget t-grid"`.. `id="grid"`?